# Spring security added to spring boot application resulting in exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, keycloak

I am trying to add spring security to a spring boot application.  Barring dependency version issues, is there anything else that I could be missing in my setup which is resulting in the exception trace below.  I have also added some dependencies from keycloak which I have copied below.

**pom**

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
        <artifactId>keycloak-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <!--Import dependency management from Spring Boot -->
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.5.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak.bom</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-adapter-bom</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0.Final</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

I added the following classes as part of the setup for spring security and keycloak:

```
import org.keycloak.adapters.springboot.KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver;
import org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.KeycloakSecurityComponents;
import org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.authentication.KeycloakAuthenticationProvider;
import org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.config.KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.mapping.SimpleAuthorityMapper;
import org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionAuthenticationStrategy;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = KeycloakSecurityComponents.class)
class SecurityConfig extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(
            AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        KeycloakAuthenticationProvider keycloakAuthenticationProvider
                = keycloakAuthenticationProvider();
        keycloakAuthenticationProvider.setGrantedAuthoritiesMapper(
                new SimpleAuthorityMapper());
        auth.authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    @Bean
    public KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver KeycloakConfigResolver() {
        return new KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver();
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
        return new RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(
                new SessionRegistryImpl());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/customers*")
                .hasRole("user")
                .anyRequest()
                .permitAll();
    }
```

as well as the following:

```
import org.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakDeployment;
import org.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakDeploymentBuilder;
import org.keycloak.adapters.spi.HttpFacade;
import org.keycloak.adapters.springboot.KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver;
import org.keycloak.adapters.springboot.KeycloakSpringBootProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class KeycloakConfigResolver extends KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver {
    private final KeycloakDeployment keycloakDeployment;

    public KeycloakConfigResolver(KeycloakSpringBootProperties properties) {
        keycloakDeployment = KeycloakDeploymentBuilder.build(properties);
    }

    @Override
    public KeycloakDeployment resolve(HttpFacade.Request facade) {
        return keycloakDeployment;
    }
}
```

Running the application with mvn spring-boot:run, I get the following exception:

```
ERROR [org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication(reportFailure):771] - Application startup failed
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/security/converter/RsaKeyConverters
    at org.springframework.security.config.crypto.RsaKeyConversionServicePostProcessor.pkcs8(RsaKeyConversionServicePostProcessor.java:89) ~[spring-security-config-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.crypto.RsaKeyConversionServicePostProcessor.postProcessBeanFactory(RsaKeyConversionServicePostProcessor.java:66) ~[spring-security-config-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:281) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:176) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:687) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:525) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.5.RELEASE.jar:1.5.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.5.RELEASE.jar:1.5.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.5.RELEASE.jar:1.5.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.5.RELEASE.jar:1.5.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.5.RELEASE.jar:1.5.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.5.RELEASE.jar:1.5.5.RELEASE]
    at com.reancloud.platform.Application.main(Application.java:16) [classes/:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:543) [spring-boot-maven-plugin-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_202]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.security.converter.RsaKeyConverters
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
    ... 19 more
2019-11-13 09:26:20 AM [main] INFO  [org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext(doClose):984] - Closing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@2480714: startup date [Wed Nov 13 09:26:17 EST 2019]; root of context hierarchy
2019-11-13 09:26:20 AM [main] WARN  [org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext(doClose):1002] - Exception thrown from LifecycleProcessor on context close
java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleProcessor not initialized - call 'refresh' before invoking lifecycle methods via the context: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@2480714: startup date [Wed Nov 13 09:26:17 EST 2019]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getLifecycleProcessor(AbstractApplicationContext.java:427) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:999) [spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:958) [spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:750) [spring-boot-1.5.5.RELEASE.jar:1.5.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) [spring-boot-1.5.5.RELEASE.jar:1.5.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.5.RELEASE.jar:1.5.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.5.RELEASE.jar:1.5.5.RELEASE]
    at com.reancloud.platform.Application.main(Application.java:16) [classes/:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:543) [spring-boot-maven-plugin-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_202]
2019-11-13 09:26:20 AM [main] ERROR [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory(destroyBean):581] - Destroy method on bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.internalCachingMetadataReaderFactory' threw an exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@2480714: startup date [Wed Nov 13 09:26:17 EST 2019]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getApplicationEventMulticaster(AbstractApplicationContext.java:414) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationListenerDetector.postProcessBeforeDestruction(ApplicationListenerDetector.java:97) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.destroy(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:253) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroyBean(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:578) [spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:554) [spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingleton(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:961) [spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingletons(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:523) [spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.destroySingletons(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:230) [spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:968) [spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1030) [spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1006) [spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:958) [spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:750) [spring-boot-1.5.5.RELEASE.jar:1.5.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) [spring-boot-1.5.5.RELEASE.jar:1.5.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.5.RELEASE.jar:1.5.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.5.RELEASE.jar:1.5.5.RELEASE]
    at com.reancloud.platform.Application.main(Application.java:16) [classes/:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:543) [spring-boot-maven-plugin-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_202]
```

Any ideas on fixing the above would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Dependency conflict:* Spring Boot 1.5.3 is for Spring Framework 4.3.8 and **Spring Security 4.2.2** (see versions [here](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-dependencies/1.5.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-dependencies-1.5.3.RELEASE.pom)), but you're including **Spring Security 5.2.1**.

Change to version 4.2.2.

Or upgrade to Spring Boot 2.2.1 and Spring Framework 5.2.1 (see versions [here](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-dependencies/2.2.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-dependencies-2.2.1.RELEASE.pom)).

Comment: i am getting another exception - will post another question

Comment: you may edit your question and mention the change in the comment.

Comment: @AbdulAlimShakir OP already asked another question, and has since deleted it, because it was a non-reproducible error.

Comment: This Answer helped me understand core of problem. Have pulled someone's project from github. In pom file:<parent><groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId><artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId><version>2.2.0</version<relativePath /> </parent>
Changed version to 2.3.6.RELEASE and remove all versions from springframework dependencies. In IntelliJIdea refresh maven.

Comment: Work like a cham